# ssh remote host ha cambiado

Tags: visual-studio, linux, ssh, virtualbox

Decidí instalar el visual studio code en mi maquina Windows y crear una maquina virtual remota Linux.

Para ahorrar recursos decidí hacer un ssh desde mi maquina principal a la virtual.

Ya instale todo en la maquina virtual pero no me deja hacer ssh en el visualcode
me salen estos errores en el el output.

```
[10:22:25.905] > @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
> IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
> Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!     
> It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
> The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
> SHA256:Rfv/+fZ47FnAY4nGhFtIEftWWdFdgelVPHK1cN9/bcQ.
> Please contact your system administrator.
> Add correct host key in C:\\Users\\stefh/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this mes
> sage.
> Offending ECDSA key in C:\\Users\\stefh/.ssh/known_hosts:1
> ECDSA host key for [127.0.0.1]:2223 has changed and you have requested strict ch
> ecking.
> Host key verification failed.
> El proceso ha intentado escribir en una canalización que no existe.
> 
[10:22:27.174] "install" terminal command done
[10:22:27.175] Install terminal quit with output: El proceso ha intentado escribir en una canalización que no existe.
[10:22:27.176] Received install output: El proceso ha intentado escribir en una canalización que no existe.
[10:22:27.177] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[10:22:27.179] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (c:\Users\stefh\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:64659)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\stefh\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:63302)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\stefh\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:415135)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async c:\Users\stefh\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:294918
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\stefh\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:406463)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\stefh\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:1:295994)
    at async c:\Users\stefh\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7\out\extension.js:127:110656
[10:22:27.188] ------
```

Soy nueva en esto así que no se a que se refiere.
gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Intenta borrar el archivo `C:\\Users\\stefh/.ssh/known_hosts` y pruebas de nuevo.

Comment: Aunque se puede borrar el archivo entero, también se puede borrar la entrada individual para el host que ha cambiado, manteniendo el resto de hosts conocidos.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, en mi caso utilizo Linux/Mac, y el comando es el siguiente:
```$ ssh-keygen -R 192.168.1.1```
Lamentablemente para Windows no se el comando ni la opción pero gracias por la aclaración.